# Checking whether a graph is connected in an immutable way

Tags: graph, scala

I have this function at the moment

```
  def isConnected(adjacencyListMap: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Boolean = {
    // Simple BFS to check whether each vertex is connected
    val visitedMap = mutable
      .Map[String, Boolean]() ++= adjacencyListMap.keys.map(vertex => vertex -> false).toMap
    val seen = mutable.Stack[String]()
    seen.push(adjacencyListMap.keys.head)

    while (seen.nonEmpty) {
      val v = seen.pop()
      visitedMap.put(v, true)
      val adjacentVertices = adjacencyListMap(v)
      adjacentVertices.foreach(adjVertex => {
        if (!visitedMap(adjVertex)) {
          visitedMap.put(adjVertex, true)
          seen.push(adjVertex)
        }
      })
    }

    // If all vertices are visited then we know all vertices are connected in 1 component
    visitedMap.values.reduce(_ && _)
  }
```

The function in essence takes in a Map where each vertex is a key and all adjacent vertices to that vertex are values. We basically do a BFS and at the end check whether all vertices were visited, if they were then we know that graph is one component and connected, if not then it is not connected.

How would I go about making this code more immutable (i.e. the mutable `seen` Stack and mutable `visitedMap` HashMap)?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review bigfocalchord. Are you only interested in improving the immutability of your code? How would you feel if someone were to post a helpful answer, but not comment on immutability?

Comment: I am happy with both! @Peilonrayz :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**completeness**

Code posted to *Code Review* should be complete, correct, and ready for review. You've got everything here except for the `import` statement needed to allow the mutable collections to compile. Sample input would also be nice but I was able to make do (I think).

**layout**

The code is organized and well presented but I do find it a bit unusual the way `mutable.Map[...` has been split. It requires a double-take to read and understand, and it doesn't really help balance the lengths of the two lines. After the `++=` would make more sense.

**Scala idioms**

Replace `map(vertex => vertex -> false)` with `map(_ -> false)`.

A `Map[String, Boolean]`, i.e. `visitedMap`, almost exactly imitates the function of a `Set[String]`, where membership is either **true** or **false**. You'd have to flip its meaning to `notVisited` and then remove each element as it gets visited. With that the final result would simply be `notVisited.isEmpty`.

Single-use variables can be useful to help document the data transformations, but in this case I don't think that `val adjacentVertices` serves much purpose. The more concise...

```
adjacencyListMap(v).foreach(adjVertex =>
```

...is equally as obvious as to what's being done.

You've got an excess (unneeded) pair of braces, `{` and `}`, surrounding the `if` statement.

Instead of reducing all the `visitedMap` values to a single boolean, all you really want to know is if there are any **false** values left behind: `visitedMap.forall(_._2)`

**immutable**

You're right, a cornerstone of Functional Programming is the use of immutable data. A common way to achieve this is via a recursive method that uses only immutable variables but passes updated data to each iteration.

```
def isConnected(adjacencyListMap: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Boolean = {
  def loop(from:Set[String], to:Set[String]): Boolean =
    if (from.isEmpty) to.isEmpty
    else (loop _).tupled(to.partition(from.flatMap(adjacencyListMap)))

  val keys = adjacencyListMap.keySet
  loop(Set(keys.head), keys.tail)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer! I am relatively new to Scala so your tips really help me nicer and functional code :D

I'll leave this question up for another few days before I tick this as answered.